# Highlight a random row in a range

Tags: excel, vba, random

I am trying to make a macro that on the press of a button highlights a random row in a selection. I have the following code (which is based on an answer generously provided by @gtwebb to @Kyle Snell):

```
Sub SelectRandom()
Dim mrg As Worksheet
Set mrg = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Merged")

Dim PopulationSelect As Range
Set PopulationSelect = mrg.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)


RandSample = Int(PopulationSelect.Rows.Count * Rnd + 1)
PopulationSelect.Rows(RandSample).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)

End Sub
```

Now on the sheet I have a header that takes up Range("A1:L5") so I'd need the code to randomly select and highlight a row from any of the rows below the header that contain data. How would I go about doing it? The code only selects and highlights the last row containing data at the moment.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give the below code a try.

```
Sub SelectRandom()
    Dim mrg As Worksheet
    Dim Rand As Long
    Dim PopulationSelect As Range

    Set mrg = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Merged")

    'Define your start row below (instead of 6)
    Rand = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(6, mrg.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    mrg.Rows(Rand).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)

End Sub
```